# App Not Running on Android Device (Tablet OS 4.0.3)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget

Recently, I uploaded an android application to Google play and checked it in various devices and it is running fine.

After a few days, my client purchased an Android tablet (Samsung Galaxy Tab GT-P3113,) which don't have GPS support, but my app uses it. Now when he tries to download this app from Google play he is getting "Device Not supported" message.

Please help me possible solutions.

Comment: You can try using Network signals instead of the actual GPS, that might work.

Comment: @Muni - is the focus of your question on how to make the app load on your client's device, or how to handle the issue with the client's device not having GPS support?

Comment: @bobnoble basically my i want to be  sure for the reasons why not it is downloaded in clients device ,although i have referred Google API docs for the same but that doesn't satisfied me.

Comment: @muni can you share manifest file if you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

When you download from g play it is a list with what applications needs/ uses.

A possibility may be that you have set a minimum android sdk and his tablet is lower that .

Another possibility ,but i am not sure, maybe in your project you had just customized folders of design without having a default one : ex: just drawable-hdmi , and no drawable

Other possibility : if the application uses maps the device has to support, you write in androidmanifest what it uses . Maybe you should do another apk and change manifest , remove maps and put it just for tablets.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when, something called **`uses-feature`** in android which is automatically checked by Play Store
and in that you might have added GPS hardware because of which your application says device not supported.

For more details on this you can visit [this link.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html)

Comment: Thanks for quick responce, but I am very sure that i haven't done so.here are the following permissions and use-feature in my app <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />     <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"></uses-feature>

Comment: Probably you can have a look into it once more.:)

Comment: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10"/> max is not defined.

Comment: any screen/dpi related stuff

Comment: <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" android:resizeable="true"/>

Comment: if you can share manifest file instead going through it again and again then it would be good, you can remove all the activities and other sensitive info which you think

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19820/discussion-between-rinkalkumar-and-muni-mishra)